# Check Duplicate Records value negative and Positive In SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I using SQL Server i have record  Expense sheet.In this table have more than 4000o Lines Of Query . I want Short duplicate Record SQL .if Which  row have  same value negative and positive Record

Example:

this is my Table

```
 Expense Id      Amount:
  1234             567
  4141             677
  3434             667
  1234           - 567
```

but this Table I have Two  Expense ID same . but value Differ Negative and Positive i want `STORE` this value  LIke

```
     Expense Id      Amount:
      1234             567

      1234           - 567
```

In table I  `Expense Id` and  `Amount`  I have Same Expense Id and but value  is Positive and negative .but is this reverse value. i want sort Like this All table get all rows in SQL.how can i  get all rows ?

Comment: edit your question and put sample data for your tables and the desired output that matches the sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can join the table with itself for opposite amounts ignoring unmatched pairs.

```
select a.* from yourTable as a
left join yourTable as b on a.ExpenseId = b.ExpenseID and a.Amount = -b.Amount
where b.ExpenseID is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select e.*
from expense e
where exists (select 1
              from expense e2
              where e2.expenseid = e.expenseid and e2.amount = - e.amount
             );
```

Comment: your correct. i want more column  field your Query . how can i add i want  ExpenseReportID .  how can i add ?

Comment: @thenna . . . (1) This returns *all* columns in `expense`.  (2) Your question doesn't mention `ExpenseReportID`.  If you have a different question, then ask it as another question and not in a comment.

Comment: its possible sort of order number negative and positive order  in select Query

Comment: @thenna . . . You can sort by `expenseid`.